# Executing javascript after clicking on wordpress permalink not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a plugin that that replaces the text  {headernav} for example with html when the wordpress page loads.  It works fine when the page first loads, however if i navigate to another page the {headernav} will show up instead of the html content that is replaced by the javascript.

Things I have tried.

1. I used firebug and discovered that the javscript is loaded when I click on the permalink and it goes to the post page.

Below is the javascript code that is loaded by the plugin.

Javascript:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){//begin document ready function call
      //place needed javascript for the plugin elements inside this function call   


     $.get("wp-content/plugins/elemental/content/headernav.php",function(element){

//the tag to replace
var headernav = "{headernav}";

//create instance of RegExp
var regEx = new RegExp(headernav,"g");

//get the html of the body
var html = $("body").html();

//replace the {headernav} with the html returned by the get method
var newValue = html.replace(regEx,element);

//update the body with the new html value
$("body").html(newValue);


});

//do not place any javascript code on or past this line
});//end document ready function call
```

Comment: So this plugin is loaded on the page that the permalink goes to as well?  by saying {nav} is showing, do you mean {headernav}?

Comment: One other thing.  Your using a relative path for your $.get().  Are you at the same root as your first page?  If you go from example.com to example.com/post then the relative link will be broken causing a error.  Which in turn would cause the $.get() to fail.

Comment: Yes,I meant {headernav}, I forgot to edit.   You are correct the path looks like this in the address bar after clicking on the permalink.                                           http://localhost/wordpress_dev/adding-an-image-test/                                       Do you have any suggestions over using relative links in my javascript file?

Comment: Any reason you would not just use a absolute path? using /wp-content/plugins/elemental/content/headernav.php for example would just start at the domain root. The other alternative is usually adding a config file that contains the root path such as the domain.

Comment: Then config file is a good idea I will consider using one. Thank You

Comment: Xeschylus, The absolute path idea would work if I add the name of the website to the front of the url you placed in your post.  The problem with that approach is that this code is in a plugin so the website name could change if the plugin is installed on a different wordpress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass variables into your plugin. Also do use the built in ajax functions by Wordpress. Take a look to [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: That did the trick(wp_localize_script). I will into look into the your built in ajax suggestion. Thank You, Larry

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, it appears to be an issue with your $.get() path which would produce an error on a 404 and not give execute the code.

An absolute path or config file will usually be sufficient by adding an a / in front of the path, so /wp-content/plugins/elemental/content/headernav.php

That will start the javascript at your domain root (www.example.com) then build from there to the path you want.

To be sure it is only on your domain I usually add a config file as well for the root rather than relying solely on using an absolute path.

Hope that helps.